# Convert a java.lang.Object to .net obejct with jni4net

Tags: c#, java, jni4net

How can I convert the double value of a jni4net proxy class `Object` to .NET `double`? Simple `Convert.ToDouble(o)` does not work, because it is nt of type `IConvertible`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to cast it to java.lang.Double on .NET side first. then the conversion to double is defined afaik.